# Identifying forked processes in linux with ps tree view

Tags: linux, treeview, fork, parent-child

Edited:

I want to make sure of something and please correct me if I'm wrong:
For the tree view of command ps ( ps auxf) it gives the following:
[image]

I do understand that this view the relationship between parent and child processes with child process cmd start with _, but does all the listed processes are either parent or child? I mean as you see above some processes cmd doesn't have relation with other processes, so I assume that these processes didn't call fork()?

Comment: I'm curious to know of what use this would be...